# My submit form tries to send the email with microsoft mail app

Tags: html

Never mind. It sent, it just didn't input any of the stuff I typed like the message. I understand the other ones are important but my main concerne is the message.

```
<div class="submitform">  
        <form id="contact" action="MAILTO:pcvanepps@gmail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
          <h3>Contact Form</h3>
          <h4>Please only contact for business inquiries. This is to request work or partnership only.</h4>
          <fieldset>
            <input placeholder="Your name" type="text" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset>
            <input placeholder="Your Email Address" type="email" tabindex="2" required>
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset>
            <input placeholder="Your Phone Number (optional)" type="text" tabindex="3" required>
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset>
            <input placeholder="Your Web Site (optional)" type="text" tabindex="4" required>
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset>
            <textarea placeholder="Type your message here...." type="text" tabindex="5" required></textarea>
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset>
            <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending" value="Send">Submit</button>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
```

Comment: That is expected behavior for MAILTO: links. What were your expectations?

Comment: The problem was that it wasn't submitting and it was trying to make me email it